# jQuery .resize event listener in separate file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a need to separate my jQuery code from my html page but am having a problem when it comes to the resize event. I have an index.html and a main.js where I want to keep all the jQuery code.

The event doesn't seem to trigger from the external js:

```
$(window).on('resize', function() {
```

The resize event does work as intended when used inline on the html page, but not when in the external js file. It is worth noting that both "Load" and "Click" events work perfectly from the external js file, but not the resize?

Comment: Do you have errors in the console ? (dev tools -> console)

Comment: Should be working as normal, try using the debugger. Is `window` null? Is your JavaScript file definitely included? Wrap that event wire-up into `$(document).ready(...)` (even if that should not be needed).

Comment: No errors.@CamilleHodoul

Comment: @UweB The file is definitely included as all the other code works fine. The window is null as far as the external file is concerned. It doesn't seem to even recognise that it exists. I've tried wrapping it inside the document.ready event but did not change anything

Comment: That is *very* strange, I've got something very similar here in my application and it's working just fine. What browser are you using, and what doctype in the HTML?

Comment: @UweB It may not be the greatest solution but I did figure out how to do this. See my answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey guys, 
Just thought anyone with the same problem might like to know, I figured out the solution to this issue. All I had to do was add in the async attribute in the HTML script tag:

```
<script src="js/main.js" type="text/javascript" async></script>
```

This set the external file to be loaded in asynchronously with the rest of the page, thus enabling